# pretender and query params

Tags: ember.js, integration-testing, qunit

I'm using the pretender lib from [Trek](https://github.com/trek/pretender) with success as long as I don't have any query params.

I've now spent officialiy 4 hours staring at the code below and can't get it to work. I'm defining an url that doesn't seem to get hit. But when i look at the call that has not been caught it is coming back with the exact url that I defined! If anybody can help me out with this one that would be great.

The test code I have:

```
var server;

module("Check Search Index page", {
  setup: function() {
    'use strict';

    Ember.run(function() {
      App.reset();

      server = new Pretender(function() {
        this.get('/api/v1/holidays.json?display_type=detail&page=1&sort%5Bprice%5D=&sort%5Bname%5D=&sort%5Brating%5D=&filter%5Bduration_min%5D=1&filter%5Bduration_max%5D=32&filter%5Bprice_min%5D=50&filter%5Bprice_max%5D=3800&filter%5Bbus%5D=true&filter%5Bflight%5D=true&filter%5Bself_transportation%5D=true', function (request) {
          return [200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, '{"holidays":[{"id":507,"name":"App. Elena"}'];
        });
      });

      server.unhandledRequest = function(verb, path, request) {
        console.log("=== BEGIN UNHANDLED REQUEST ===");
        console.log('verb: ' + verb);
        console.log('path: ' + path);
        console.log('request: ' + request);
        console.log("=== END UNHANDLED REQUEST ===");
      };
    });
  },

  teardown: function() {
    'use strict';

    server.shutdown();
  }
});

test('Search page', function() {
  'use strict';

  visit('/search/index');
  andThen(function() {
    ok(find('p:contains("Bepaal uw zoek criteria")').length, 'Search page is showing');
  });
});
```

And the error message I get in the console:

```
.=== BEGIN UNHANDLED REQUEST ===
verb: GET
path: /api/v1/holidays.json?display_type=detail&page=1&sort%5Bprice%5D=&sort%5Bname%5D=&sort%5Brating%5D=&filter%5Bduration_min%5D=1&filter%5Bduration_max%5D=32&filter%5Bprice_min%5D=50&filter%5Bprice_max%5D=3800&filter%5Bbus%5D=true&filter%5Bflight%5D=true&filter%5Bself_transportation%5D=true
request: [object Object]
=== END UNHANDLED REQUEST ===
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should't define the query params in the request definition. For the code above to work the definition of the end point should be:

```
  server = new Pretender(function() {
    this.get('/api/v1/holidays.json?', function (request) {
      return [200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, '{"holidays":[{"id":507,"name":"App. Elena"}'];
    });
  });
```